# Can't save the images names from drawable in a String[]

Tags: java, eclipse

I have in my drawable folder my photos with names photo_1,photo_2 etc. I want to save only these images in my database. I have a table with fields (id, name). This function must return a string array with the images names (not all the images names of the drawable just that a called photo_1 etc).
I get an error here "cur[r] = s;". Can't understand why...
Can anyone help?

```
public static String[] getImagesNames()
{
int r=0;
String s;
String[] cur=null, nam=null;
Field[] dr = R.drawable.class.getFields();
for(Field f : dr)

s = "R.drawable."+f.getName();
cur[r] = s;
r++;
}
for(int j=0;j<=r;j++)
{
for(int k=0;k<=r;k++)
{
if((cur[j]).equals("photo_"+k))
{
nam[j] = cur[j];
}
}
}
return nam;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You initialized `cur` to `null` at statement `String[] cur=null`, that's why can't access any variables.

You need to initialize it something like `String[] cure = new String[dr.length]` but put the declaration of `dr` before this one